# DOM events loading challenge with D3 graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dom

I am new to D3 /Javascript / html and I just made my first interactive viz.  Its 93% done, but I have coded myself into a corner. There is a toggle switch on the graph which changes the numbers from counts to percentages. When the toggle is switched the graph appears, but I can't figure out how to get the graph to render upon loading without the click event while maintaining the functionality of the toggle feature which happens to load the data.

The likely culprits are here:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

//Initialize with vanilla counts
var fileName = "data.csv"
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
```

The full code is available here:
https://www.philippou.us/jensweb/interactive_viz.html

How can I get my D3 graph to load without someone clicking on the toggle switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the code after "checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {", i.e., from "if (checkbox.checked) {" down, into a function, e.g., "function drawGraph() { ...}". Calling the function in the change event will be exactly what you're doing now. Then add a call to the function at the end of loading the page, e.g., "[script]drawGraph();[/script]" just before the "[/body]" statement. (Note: I'm using square brackets rather than angle brackets around script and body because they don't display otherwise and I don't know how to make them display. Sorry.)